# IndexedDB onupgradeneeded Event target is null on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, indexeddb

I am developing a Cordova App for iOS with an IndexedDB Database in the background. Here is my code for opening the database:

```
indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.shimIndexedDB;

            window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
            window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;
            if (!indexedDB) {
                window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.");
            }

            console.log("openDb ...");
            var req = indexedDB.open(insectDbName, 21);
            console.log(req);

            req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
                debugger;
                db = this.result;
                console.log("openDb DONE");
            };
            req.onerror = function(evt) {
                //debugger;
                console.error("openDb: ", evt.target.errorCode);
            };

            req.onupgradeneeded = function(evt) {
                console.log("openDb.onupgradeneeded");

                //debugger;


                var versionStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(versionStoreName, { autoIncrement : true});
                console.log("versionStore created");
            };
```

Now, my problem is, when I open the database, the request is no `IDBOpenRequest` object. But the events are firing. When I open the database with a new version number, the `onupgradeneeded` event is called. And when I open with the current version, the `onsuccess` event is called.
The problem is, that the objectstores are never created, because in the `onupgradeneeded` event, `evt.currentTarget` is null.

I have already included the [IndexedDBshim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim) and the [Cordova IndexedDB Plugin](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-indexedDB) but it is still not working.

Has anybody encountered similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I had to use `evt.target` instead of `evt.currentTarget`.